Getting bad gateway from other k3s clusters when deploying a sample nginx app with traefik in front of it
I'm trying to learn k3s by deploying a simple nginx app where I use configmaps as a volume to mount my index.html file.
I use Vagrant to spin up 3 Ubuntu nodes:
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu2204"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "1024"
  end

  config.vm.define "master" do |master|
    master.vm.hostname = "master"
    master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.2"
  end

  config.vm.define "node1" do |node1|
    node1.vm.hostname = "node1"
    node1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.11"
  end

  config.vm.define "node2" do |node2|
    node2.vm.hostname = "node2"
    node2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.22"
  end
end

$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME     STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION        INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master   Ready    control-plane,master   24h   v1.29.5+k3s1   192.168.56.2    <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS   5.15.0-91-generic   containerd://1.7.15-k3s1
node1    Ready    <none>                 24h   v1.29.5+k3s1   192.168.56.11   <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS   5.15.0-91-generic   containerd://1.7.15-k3s1
node2    Ready    <none>                 24h   v1.29.5+k3s1   192.168.56.22   <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS   5.15.0-91-generic   containerd://1.7.15-k3s1

# Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: hello-world-volume
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
      - name: hello-world-volume
        configMap:
          name: hello-world
---
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: hello-world
---
# Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  annotations:
    spec.ingressClassName: "traefik"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-world-service
            port:
              number: 80

This seems to work but when I add more replicas replicas: 3. If I keep refreshing the page, I would get the output I expected 1 out of 3 times, but 2 out of 3 times I get a Bad Gateway error.
